# KeyError: ' http' Url Parsing Error

Tags: python, api, odoo-10, httplib2, shopware

I am currently working on shopware API When I am parsing the URL of 
like

http://192.168.0.100/shopware531/api

and give me an error that:~

```
connection_type = SCHEME_TO_CONNECTION[scheme]
KeyError: u' http'
```

Using the

```
def buildHttpQuery(self, taxonomy, parameters):
    if taxonomy.startswith('/'):
        taxonomy = taxonomy[1:]
    if not self.baseurl.endswith('/'):
        self.baseurl += '/'
    url = urljoin(self.baseurl, taxonomy)
    url_parts = list(urlparse(url))
    query = dict(parse_qsl(url_parts[4]))
    query.update(parameters)

    url_parts[4] = urlencode(query)

    url = urlunparse(url_parts)
    return url
```

and url return is :~ http://192.168.0.100/shopware531/api

[image: Here Full stack of error]

Comment: Please add the full error traceback.

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: Add the full Traceback @KlausD.

Comment: Any text (including the traceback) must be _pasted_ into your original question. We cannot read the smallprint of your low-res image.

Comment: Looks like there a space at the beginning of the URL causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similiar problem but with bytes. I have link like: `b"https://google.com"` and I use `httplib2.request(str(link))` because this request wants string instead of bytes.  Later on debugger I saw that str function transforms `b'https://google.com'` into `b'https://google.com'` and cause KeyError. So after using  `b'https://google.com'.decode('utf-8')` it works.